# Where is my question when I ask is it okay for muslims to vote for non muslims governor?

Tags: discussion

I think I had that question. Where was it?

I wanted to ask a follow up question whether muslims are allowed to ally with secular parties and propose non muslim candidate. The party that says that muslims cannot vote for non muslims did exactly that in other provinces in my country.

Comment: Are you sure have you checked whether it was edited? I couldn't make out such a question in your profile! Have you asked it via a different account?

Comment: Maybe it was flagged as a duplicate of [this question](https://islam.stackexchange.com/questions/36294/can-a-muslim-vote-for-non-muslim-governors-or-presidents). Therefore it's now deleted.

Answer (score 2):

The question and answer for it still exist you've created it with a different account as it seems:
[Can a Muslim vote for non-Muslim governors or presidents?](https://islam.stackexchange.com/questions/36294/can-a-muslim-vote-for-non-muslim-governors-or-presidents)

There's no such question in your other (supposed) accounts. You may consider merging your accounts for a how-to see [here](https://islam.stackexchange.com/help/merging-accounts) in our help-center